# How do you configure Mathematica 9 to automatically evaluate all notebooks?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a Mathematica 6 course that I am using in Mathematica 9; there is no updated version. Every time I open a notebook I have to go to the Evaluation menu and click on "Evaluate Notebook". Is there a way for me to set it so that it automatically evaluates a notebook upon my opening it?

Comment: Anthony you might consider joining the mathematica stackexchange forum http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can setup the initialization cells. Check [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/menuitem/InitializationCell.html) and [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/WorkWithInitializationCells.html). Afterwards, you can just open a notebook and just evaluate any cell (e.g. `2+2` -> Shift+Enter) and accept to run all initialization cells.
One thing that helped me was checking `NotebookEvaluate` in the docs - this way I can evaluate all cells in another notebook without even having to open it.

You may find further information about options for cells in [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OptionsForCells.html).

Comment: But this method requires manual intervention! I am looking to have everything evaluated *automatically* upon opening a notebook.

Comment: Well, I don't know about that. I guess you should consider following @magma's advice